# Why can't I put a comma in a \newtcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

When I try to put a "," in the mybox environment, I get the error:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/FM and PM and Narrowband F
>   M' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Is there a way to put a comma "," in the tcolorbox header so that my header appears as: Angle, FM, and PM and Narrowband FM?

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minibox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=0.97\textwidth,fontupper=\scriptsize,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize, colbacktitle=black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners},top=3pt,bottom=2pt,
  title=#2,colback=white}

%%------------ Angle, FM and PM and Narrowband FM ---------------
\hspace{-0.2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.31\textwidth}
    \begin{mybox}{Angle FM and PM and Narrowband FM}

\lipsum[2]

    \end{mybox}
\end{minipage}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Gilles's answer is the best, you can change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just put the title with the comma into two more `{ }`, otherwise, I think `tcolorbox` thinks there is another parameter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minibox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=0.97\textwidth,fontupper=\scriptsize,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize, colbacktitle=black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners},top=3pt,bottom=2pt,
  title=#2,colback=white}

%%------------ Angle, FM and PM and Narrowband FM ---------------
\hspace{-0.2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.31\textwidth}
    \begin{mybox}{{Angle, FM and PM and Narrowband FM}}

\lipsum[2]

    \end{mybox}
\end{minipage}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Brace the value for `title`, so when the parameter is replaced by the actual title the comma will not be mistaken for a key-value separator.

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  %text width=0.97\textwidth,%<--- avoid this
  fontupper=\scriptsize,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize,
  colbacktitle=black,
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
  boxed title style={sharp corners},
  top=3pt,
  bottom=2pt,
  title={#2},% <------ Braces!
  colback=white
}
```

Full example. I recommend avoiding to set `text width`, so it will be computed automatically. I load `lipsum` and `showframe` just to show the effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  fontupper=\scriptsize,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize,
  colbacktitle=black,
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
  boxed title style={sharp corners},
  top=3pt,
  bottom=2pt,
  title={#2},
  colback=white
}

\begin{document}

%%------------ Angle, FM and PM and Narrowband FM ---------------
\begin{mybox}{Angle, FM and PM and Narrowband FM}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you write `\tcolorbox[title=Angle, FM, and PM and Narrowband FM,colback=white]`, when `\tcolorbox` parses its bracketed argument, it looks for commas to separate options. It has no way to know that you intended `FM` to still be part of the title, but `colback` to be a separate option. You need to hide the non-option-separating comma inside a braced group: `\tcolorbox[title={Angle, FM, and PM and Narrowband FM},colback=white]`. Braced groups are parsed before passing the argument to the command, therefore what `tcolorbox` sees inside the square brackets is `t`, `i`, `t`, `l`, `e`, `=`, {Angle, FM, and PM and Narrowband FM}`,`,`,`c`,`o`,`l`, … It's always ok to put the whole argument of an option inside braces.

The same applies with `newtcolorbox`, with the added wrinkle that expanding `#2` into the argument of the command happens before the argument parsing. There is no implicit group around `#2`, so to cope with arbitrary arguments, you need to add braces.

```
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{
  text width=0.97\textwidth,
  fontupper=\scriptsize,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize,
  colbacktitle=black,
  enhanced,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
  boxed title style={sharp corners},
  top=3pt, bottom=2pt,
  title={#2},
  colback=white
}
```

Note how the argument to `attach boxed title to top left` uses braces for the same reason.

The braces should be around the whole argument to the `title` option, not specifically around the argument of the command. For example, if you wanted to add a common prefix to all the titles, you should write

```
  title={Joe's tips: #2},
```

There wouldn't be any difference in this particular case, but sometimes braces can have a subtle influence over spacing or over the action of some commands that define macros locally. The argument of an option becomes a braced group deep under the hood, so putting braces around it doesn't change anything, whereas building additional braced groups over *part* of the argument can change things.

The same principle applies generally with many commands. It's a low-level TeX thing.

Comment: +1 for explaining the actual problem in detail :) But, although the observed behavior makes sense from a technical (or TeXnical as it is sometimes called) perspective, it is rather counterintuitive for the user - you would expect that `tcolorbox` (in this case `\newtcolorbox`) would try to hide such implementation issues from the user if possible.

Comment: @Marijn Unfortunately that's not possible without major changes to TeX which would break all the TeX and LaTeX code out there. TeX wasn't designed in a way that makes it easy to add functionality such as named arguments to macro.